# GSM USSD Modem Request

Tags: c#, gsm, modem

How can I send a USSD request via GSM modem using c#.

I want to be able to execute any code and the response should come back as an object or string that I can use against a regex

Comment: A little more information is necessary to answer this question...  C# doesn't include native support for this.  Are you using any libraries?

Comment: I am using GSM Comm library

Answer (score 1):

Here is my extract that i have used with the GSM COmm library

```
   public string SendUssdRequest(string request)
  {
    log.DebugFormat("Sending USSD Request {0}", request);
    string result = "";
    try
    {
        IProtocol protocol = comm.GetProtocol();
        string gottenString = protocol.ExecAndReceiveMultiple("AT+CUSD=1," + request + ",15");
        result = gottenString;
        int i = 0;
        if (!gottenString.Contains("\r\n+CUSD: 2"))
        {
            bool receiving = false;
            do
            {
                receiving = protocol.Receive(out gottenString);
                result += gottenString;
                ++i;
            } while (receiving);
        }

        result = result.Replace("\r\n", "");

        result = result.Replace("+CUSD: 2,", "");
        result = result.Replace(",15", "");
        log.DebugFormat("{1} - USSD Response is:  {0}", result,SenderNumber);
        return result;
    }
    catch(Exception ex) 
    {
        log.Error(ex);
    }
    finally
    {

        comm.ReleaseProtocol();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: I will try this. Thanks for the response

Comment: What is the SenderNumber variable and I assume comm is the GSM comm object?

Comment: The sender number is another property that ive stored in my class. You can remove this or set the actual phone number if you track it

Comment: Ah this seems to work. I wasn't looping for the response. Thanks for the help @Scrappy